# (Automator) Offline Shell Script Execution

Tags: xml, bash, automator

So I've got this `Run Shell Script (/bin/bash)`:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
curl -o ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist http://launched.zerowidth.com/plists/XXX-YYY-ZZZ.xml
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist
```

And I want to make this work offline. So curl doesn't fetch `http://launched.zerowidth.com/plists/XXX-YYY-ZZZ.xml` from the Internet, but from offline, considering I have downloaded the .xml file and imported it onto Automator somehow.

XXX-YYY-ZZZ.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.zerowidth.launched.test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>echo test</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>20</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @I0_ol I want to execute the bash script offline. Meaning I'd have to load the .xml file from my Computer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple ping would probably help to determine if you're on-line

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
if ping -c 1 launched.zerowidth.com > /dev/null ; then
    curl -o ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist http://launched.zerowidth.com/plists/XXX-YYY-ZZZ.xml launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist
else
    cp the_file_you_downloaded ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist
fi
```

Comment: This won't help. I want to import the .xml file offline (after I've downloaded it). How do I do that?

Comment: I fail to see your problem with the cp, but curl -o ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist file://the_file_you_downloaded launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.zerowidth.launched.test.plist instead of the cp would probably be your answer.